# How to display text on android when certain SMS message is received

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm new to android development and java programming. i just wanted to know how to print or display certain text if this "certain" message is received.
[I got this code on the web on how to receive and read SMS](https://web.archive.org/web/20130327004652/http://androidexample.com/Incomming_SMS_Broadcast_Receiver_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=62&aaid=87).

ReadIncomingSms.java

```
package readnewsms.adk;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

// Get the object of SmsManager
final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
 
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 
    // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try {
         
        if (bundle != null) {
             
            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
             
            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                 
                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])    pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                 
                String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                
                

                Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);
                 
                
               // Show Alert
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, 
                             "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                toast.show();
                
                
            }
            // end for loop
          } // bundle is null 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);
         
    }
}
```

}

then i added this code after toast.show(); still inside the loop

```
if  (message.equals(("1"))){
                    System.out.println("user sends 1");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("other");
                }
```

what do i do to display those messages on the screen? or how do i evaluate the code if the message contains a certain value, then i will print a certain message depending on the message sent. for example if the INCOMING message contains 1, then the app will display user sends 1.

Comment: Do you want those messages to be in a toast?

Comment: Can you specify where you are trying to Display?

Comment: I was just going to ask what @hichris123 asked. It seems like you do. How about changing the toast message instead?

Comment: @hichris123 did you mean the values i want to display and not the incoming message? no . I just wanted to know how to determine if a certain value or string is present on the messaged sent. then i will execute a certain message. thanks

Comment: It looks like you are checking whatthe message contains. So if a person sends one, what do you want to do with that information? Display a toast? Update a textview?

Comment: update a textview. but how do i do that. i want to display a message when for example an incoming message contains "1"

Comment: Do you want this message to be on the screen, or in your LogCat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to put a `Toast` on the screen. This displays a little message at the bottom. The code would look like this:

```
if  (message.equals(("1"))){
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "User sent 1");
    toast.show();
                } else {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Other);
                    toast.show();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if (message.contains("1")) {
    //do something is message contains string '1' anywhere
    Log.d("MYTAG", "user send 1");
}
```

or

```
if (message.equals("1")) {
    //do something if the whole message equals to string '1'
    Log.d("MYTAG", "user send 1");
}
```

Read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) about String methods.

To update textView (assuming you have one defined in xml), find it with findViewById() and then use:

```
myTextView.setText("user send 1")
```

You can also display a message in logcat, so instead of using System.out.println(), use:

```
Log.d("MYTAG", "user send 1");
```

or whatever message you want. More on layouts [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

Comment: as you can see on the code above, i already tried the if (message.equals("1")) {} but nothing is displaying. i was wondering if System.out.println() is the right code for displaying message.

Comment: Use logcat, eg. Log.d("MYTAG", "use send 1") instead of System.out.println

Comment: Also, are you actually registering your receiver anywhere? Is your onReceive() method being called at all?

Comment: okay. i'll try that. thank you :) i will update if it will work.